# Killing a process windows CE

Tags: windows-ce, kill-process

I need to implement a program that will run on Windows CE 6.0, in C++, and that aims to kill a specific process at a specific moment.

I have tried to use 'TerminateProcess(ProcessHandle, ExitCode)'. It works, and kills the process whose handle I passed. However, when killing the specific process I want to kill, the machine stops responding, which is not acceptable.

I can kill the process via tellnet, if I use:

```
telnet 10.120.12.5   (IP of the Windows CE machine)
shell -d            
kp 6522589           (example ID of the proccess)
```

That works. It kills the process and the machine does not stop running.

So the question is, how can I insert this command into my code? or, how can I call a script which does this from my code? (the script will have to be stored inside the windows CE machine).

Any other suggestion will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the `ProcessHandle`? You usually need to free it with `CloseHandle()` after you are done with it (after calling `TerminateProcess()`).

You can use `CreateProcess()` to run another program, e.g. the shell/kp program.